# nodejs: how to connect to another nodejs server when changing room with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is my JS script (it uses nodejs and socket.io on server side)

```
<script src="http://myserver.com:1339/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
socket = io.connect('http://myserver.com:1339');    
socket.emit('enterRoom', myuser, room);
```

What I am strying to achieve is to change server (http://myserver2.com:1339) when room is for instance "room2"

I have no idea how to do that without refresing the whole page.

Any tip is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var socket = io.connect(
  room === 'room2' ? 'http://myserver2.com:1339' : 'http://myserver.com:1339');
);
```

(you don't have to reload the `socket.io.js` file).

Comment: I tried this already with no success.
It seems server does not emit to the client socket object

Comment: @user300675 but you are seeing the connection being made on the server?

Comment: yes: I see the connection on Server !
But when server emits to client, client does not recieve it.

Comment: socket.on('connect', function(){
 alert("I am now connected");
 socket = io.connect('http://myserver2.com:1339');  
});
DOES NOT WORK

Comment: hmm wait, you're connecting to a new server from inside an existing event handler? that won't work. You need to set up all the event handlers again after connecting to a new server.

Comment: yes: I thoought about that alreday. 
I am using anonymous function such as: 
socket.on("connect", function() {...})

DO I have to use: 
socket.on("connect",connectFunction);

Comment: @user300675 yes, that would probably be the most obvious solution :) And move all event handler setup into `connectFunction`.